# How do I get a drop down/select option have Multiple Values

Tags: php, forms, html-select

I've read other questions on here that dealt with what I am looking for. But it still did not help me.
I want to have multiple values in an option of the select tag of a form that will be posting the information onto a different file that is viewable to the visitor by iframe. Example of what I am trying to do:

The following is on the file: **Form.php**

```
<div>
<form action"blank.php" method="post" target="box">
<select name="g1">
<option name="g1" value="Value 1, Value 2"> Text </option>
<option name="g1" value="Value 1, Value 2"> Text Blah </option>
</select>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</div>
<iframe src="blank.php" name="box"></iframe>
```

The Following is a long the lines of what I **want** to appear on the: **blank.php** which is visible by iframe.

**Option 1 or 2 value's should appear like this**

> [ Value 1 ]  [ Value 2 ]

**An Example:**

Its a drop down menu that will post two seperate values when you select one option. 
Like if I selected an option that says **Hola - hello** and it will post:

> **[Hola] means [Hello].**

and the option tag would have the values as:

```
<option name="g1" value="Hola, Hello">Hola - Hello</option>
```

Comment: Give your field a name that ends with [] (e.g. <select name="g1[]">). See http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need a `name` attribute on each of your `<option>` elements. Just the `<select>` box.

Second of all, I think all you need is the handy dandy [`explode` function](http://php.net/explode). You'll get the value like this...

```
$values = $_POST['g1'];
```

...and then split them into an array like this...

```
$values = explode(', ', $values);
```

...and finally just access the values like so:

```
$value1 = $values[0];
$value2 = $values[1];
```

Comment: And how would I put that into a full working code? Sorry I really am not familiar with PHP at all.

Comment: This would be in your blank.php page. Put this at the top, and then you have `$value1` and `$value2` to work with. So, for example, you could then do `echo "[$value1] means [$value2]";`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to build an array of your form fields where multiple values are allowed. Read the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.select-multiple) for more.

From the manual:

> **How do I get all the results from a select multiple HTML tag?**
>
> The
>   select multiple tag in an HTML construct allows users to select
>   multiple items from a list. These items are then passed to the action
>   handler for the form. The problem is that they are all passed with the
>   same widget name. I.e.
>
> ```
> <select name="var" multiple="yes">
> ```
>
> Each selected option will arrive at the action handler as:
>
> ```
> var=option1
> var=option2
> var=option3
> ```
>
> Each option will overwrite the contents of the previous $var variable.
>   The solution is to use PHP's "array from form element" feature. The
>   following should be used:
>
> ```
> <select name="var[]" multiple="yes">
> ```
>
> This tells PHP to treat `$var` as an array and each assignment of a
>   value to `var[]` adds an item to the array. The first item becomes
>   `$var[0]`, the next `$var[1]`, etc. The `count()` function can be used to
>   determine how many options were selected, and the `sort()` function can
>   be used to sort the option array if necessary. Note that if you are
>   using JavaScript the `[]` on the element name might cause you problems
>   when you try to refer to the element by name. Use it's numerical form
>   element ID instead, or enclose the variable name in single quotes and
>   use that as the index to the elements array, for example:
>
> ```
> variable = document.forms[0].elements['var[]'];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is in the PHP section, but what you are trying to do would be much easier to achieve with javascript.  If you change the iframe tags to:

```
<div id="valueDisplay"></div>
```

and add an ID and listener to the select

```
<select name="g1" id="dropDown" onchange="showValues()">
<option name="g1" value="1"> Text </option>
<option name="g1" value="2"> Text Blah </option>
</select>
```

You just write a little script like this and put it in the body somewhere:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showValues(){
    var outDiv = document.getElementById('valueDisplay');
    var selectValue = document.getElementById('dropDown').value;
    var divText;
    if(selectValue == 1) divText = '[ Value 1 ][ Value 2 ]';
    if(selectValue == 2) divText = '[ Value 1 ][ Value 2 ]';
    outDiv.innerHTML = divText;
}
</script>
```

To achieve what you are trying to do with iframes would be more difficult.  It would require you to use javascript/jquery to post the data within the iframe.

Note that using onchange="" is no longer the accepted method of adding listeners.  It is just easier if you are not familiar with javascript.

Comment: I think using the target attribute, as OP did, totally handles submitting the data.

Comment: @sdlelhssirhc I stand corrected.. Didn't know that one could target another frame with a form.